# Implementing a Thread Array in Matrix

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, matrix

My assignment is to make a project that takes the inputted dimensions of two matrixes and have the user select the operation he wishes to perform on those matrixes and output the result matrix.  The added twist is that it has to be done in parallel. For every element/cell the resultant matrix has there has to be one thread.  For example 2x2 and another 2x2 matrices output 4 elements.  So there must be 4 threads each performing the operation on each element. Here is my code for a matrix:

```
 public class Matrix {
        public int row,column;
        private double [][] matrixElements;

        public Matrix (int rows, int columns){
            this.row= rows;
            this.column = columns;
            matrixElements = new double[row][column];
            populatematrix(-100,100);
        }


        public Matrix(double[][] matrixArray){
            this.row = matrixArray.length;
            this.column = (matrixArray[0]).length;
            matrixElements = new double [row][column];
            for (int i=0; i<row;i++){
                for (int j=0; j<column;j++){
                     matrixElements[i][j] = matrixArray[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
         private void populatematrix(int min, int max){
             Random randnum = new Random();
             Random rand = new Random();

              for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
                  for (int j= 0;i<row;i++){
                      matrixElements[i][j] = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
                  }
              }
         }
         public Matrix add(Matrix otherMatrix){
             double[][] resultMatrixArray = new double[this.row][this.column];
             for (int i=0; i<row; i++){
                 for (int j=0; j<column; j++){ 
                     resultMatrixArray[i][j] = this.matrixElements[i][j] + otherMatrix.matrixElements[i][j];

                 }

             }
             return new Matrix(resultMatrixArray);
         }

         public Matrix subtract(Matrix otherMatrix){
             double[][] resultMatrixArray = new double[row][column];

             for (int i=0; i<row; i++){ 
                 for (int j=0; j<column; j++){
                     resultMatrixArray[i][j] = this.matrixElements[i][j] - otherMatrix.matrixElements[i][j];
                 }
             } 
             return new Matrix(resultMatrixArray);

         }




        public Matrix dotProduct(Matrix otherMatrix){

            double[][] resultMatrixArray = new double [row][column];

            double sum = 0;

            if (this.column !=otherMatrix.row)
                System.out.println("\n\n Matrices Multiplication is not possible...Invalid Dimensions...\n\n");
            else {
                for (int c=0; c<this.row;c++){
                    for (int d = 0; d<otherMatrix.column;d++){
                        for (int k = 0; k<otherMatrix.row; k++){
                            sum = sum+((this.matrixElements[c][k])*(otherMatrix.matrixElements[k][d]));
                        }
                        resultMatrixArray[c][d]=sum;
                        sum = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            return new Matrix(resultMatrixArray);
        }

        public String getPrintableMatrix(){
            String result ="";

            for (double[] roww: matrixElements){
                for (double j:roww){
                    result +=""+j + "";

                }
                result +="\n";

            }
            return result;
        }
}
```

Here is my code for the methods used to find the result of a matrix for any of the operations.

```
public class MatrixOperations {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int row1,col1,row2,col2;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\n\n Input Matrix 1 dimensions (ROWS space COLUMNS):");
        row1= sc.nextInt();
        col1 = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\n\n Input Matrix 2 dimensions (ROWS space COlUMNS):");
        row2= sc.nextInt();
        col2 = sc.nextInt();

        int operation;

         System.out.print("\n\n Select the operation to executed: 1. Add 2. Subtract 3. Multiply \n > ");
         operation = sc.nextInt();

         Matrix result;
         Matrix m1 = new Matrix(row1, col1);
         Matrix m2 = new Matrix(row2, col2);

         Thread myThreads[] = new Thread[Matrix.row];
        switch(operation){
            case 1:
                result = m1.add(m2);
                System.out.println("\n\n First Matrix: \n " + m1.getPrintableMatrix());
                System.out.println("\n\n Second Matrix: \n " + m2.getPrintableMatrix());
                System.out.println("\n\n Resultant Matrix: \n " + result.getPrintableMatrix());

                break;

            case 2:
                result = m1.subtract(m2);

                 System.out.println("\n\n First Matrix: \n " + m1.getPrintableMatrix());
                 System.out.println("\n\n Second Matrix: \n " + m2.getPrintableMatrix());
                 System.out.println("\n\n Resultant Matrix: \n " + result.getPrintableMatrix());


                 break;

            case 3:

                result = m1.dotProduct(m2);

                 System.out.println("\n\n First Matrix: \n " + m1.getPrintableMatrix());
                 System.out.println("\n\n Second Matrix: \n " + m2.getPrintableMatrix());
                 System.out.println("\n\n Resultant Matrix: \n " + result.getPrintableMatrix());

                 break;

            default: System.out.println("\nInvalid operation......\n");break;
        }

        System.out.print("\n\n");
    }
```

}

This is my code for user input.

My question is how would I make this parallel. This is my first parallel project and I know I have to use an array of threads but I don't know where to put them, I've tried multiple ways and no one seems able to help me.

I know that it requires an array of threads and the number of arrays needed is the amount of elements in output matrix, but I don't know where or how to implement the array as I get an error in the multiple ways I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change code structure, otherwise it may be too complicated for incorporation with Threads.

- Move atomic operations on matrix elements ("+", "-", "*") into corresponding Functional Interfaces
- Create a separate function, which processes matrix, otherMatrix and required operation and hides all the concurrency inside
- In above function start ExecutorService with required amount of Threads (4 in the example below) and shut it down when all the tasks are submitted
- Identify result Matrix row/column count before applying the operation. (*) Note there is a possible mistake in your code, in `dotProduct` function result Matrix size is not neccessary `new double [row][column]`

Please, see the code below

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Matrix {

@FunctionalInterface
interface MatrixOperation<Matrix, Integer> {
    public void apply(Matrix m1, Matrix m2, Matrix m3, Integer i, Integer j);
}
private final static MatrixOperation<Matrix, Integer> addFunc = (m1, m2, m3, i, j) -> {
    double value = m1.get(i, j) + m2.get(i, j);
    m3.set(i, j, value);
};
private final static MatrixOperation<Matrix, Integer> subtractFunc = (m1, m2, m3, i, j) -> {
    double value = m1.get(i, j) + m2.get(i, j);
    m3.set(i, j, value);
};
private final static MatrixOperation<Matrix, Integer> productFunc = (m1, m2, m3, i, j) -> {
    double value = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < m1.column; index++) {
        value += m1.get(i, index) * m2.get(index, j);
    }
    m3.set(i, j, value);
};
//Set number of threads
private final static int threadCount = 4;

public int row, column;
private double[][] matrixElements;


public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
    this.row = rows;
    this.column = columns;
    matrixElements = new double[row][column];
}


public Matrix(double[][] matrixArray) {
    this.row = matrixArray.length;
    this.column = (matrixArray[0]).length;
    matrixElements = new double[row][column];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            matrixElements[i][j] = matrixArray[i][j];
        }
    }
}

public double get(int i, int j) {
    return matrixElements[i][j];
}

public void set(int i, int j, double value) {
    matrixElements[i][j] = value;
}

private Matrix operation(Matrix m2, Matrix result, MatrixOperation<Matrix, Integer> operator) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < result.column; j++) {
            final int i1 = i;
            final int j1 = j;
            executor.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    operator.apply(Matrix.this, m2, result, i1, j1);
                }
            });

        }
    }
    try {
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

public Matrix add(final Matrix m2) {
    if (this.row != m2.row || this.column != m2.column) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return operation(m2, new Matrix(row, column), addFunc);
}

public Matrix subtract(Matrix m2) {
    if (this.row != m2.row || this.column != m2.column) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return operation(m2, new Matrix(row, column), subtractFunc);
}


public Matrix dotProduct(Matrix m2) {
    if (this.column != m2.row) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    return operation(m2, new Matrix(row, m2.column), productFunc);
}

}
```

Several tips:

- In this case it makes no sense number of threads to be more the the number of cores on your machine, it will make the code slower.
- (!) `ExecutorService.shutdown()` forces executor to complete all running tasks without accepting new one.  `ExecutorService.awaitTermination` stops main Thread until all the tasks are finished. Ie, result matrix will
  be fully constructed before it is returned.
- As long as different threads are reading from matrix and otherMatrix, which must not be updated during the calculation, and write to different locations (i, j) of result matrix, the code is thread-safe.

Comment: Hi thank you also for helping me with this issue, I'm new to threads and parallel programming and this helped me tremendously thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alright fair enough, seems like you made a great effort and willing to learn more so here is my 2 cent:

You have a farm. **139 meter** long. Every year you collect ( lets say ) potatoes yourself. You spent **1 hour** per meter. So if you work **12** hour per day harvesting per year takes around **12** day (139/12). 
 Then you made some money and you hire **8** guy . How you will share the land equally:

```
139 is not dividable by 8
```

So lets do some clean up and find the difference:

`139 % 8 = 3` ([modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation))

So now you know you have extra **3** meter that you can handle yourself. And other guys can handle this way:

```
(Total - Difference) / workers = meters per worker
```

if we fill in the blanks:

```
(139 - 3) / 8 = 17
```

So we know each worker will work for **17** meter. Wait, but all of them should not work for the first 17 meter!!! We need to equally divide

So we will give each worker an id:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

And then we will tell the workers where to start and where to end by using their id:

```
  start = id * step
  end = start + step
```

which will result as start ,end:

```
  worker 0 will work: 0 until 17 (not including 17, 0 indexed ;))
  worker 1 will work: 17 until 34
  worker 2 will work: 34 until 51
  worker 3 will work: 51 until 68
  worker 4 will work: 68 until 85
  worker 5 will work: 85 until 102
  worker 6 will work: 102 until 119
  worker 7 will work: 119 until 136

  and you = 136 until 139 (3 meter)
```

So since you have multi dimensional array, you have inner loops like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                resultMatrixArray[i][j] = this.matrixElements[i][j] + otherMatrix.matrixElements[i][j];

            }

        }
```

What you need to do that you will create [threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) and tell each of them where to **start** and where to **end**:

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                resultMatrixArray[i][j] = thisMatrix[i][j] + otherMatrix[i][j];

            }

        }
```

And then you can do the math and do something like that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < threadCount;i++){
            int start = i * step;
            int end = start  + step;

   new Thread(new Add(....)).run();


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate all your time in helping me, it gave me a fresh view and now I finally know what to do thank you!